# Create new folder from files name and move files

Tags: applescript, automator

*(This is a new edit from a previous question of mine which achieved -3 votes. Hope this new one has a better qualification)*

I need to create an **Automator service** to organize a high amount of files into folders. I work with **illustrator** and from each **.ai** file I create **3 more formats**: [**name.pdf**], [**name BAJA.jpg**] and [**name.jpg**], thats 4 files in total

My problem is that during the week I repeat this process to more than 90 different .ai files. So 90 files * 4 is **360 independent files** all into the some project folder.

I want to grab all 4 related files into one folder, and **set the folder name as the same as the .ai file**.

Since all the file names are identical (except one), I thought of telling the finder to grab all the files with the same name, copy the name, create a folder and put this files inside, but I have a file name variant [name LOW.jpg] Maybe I can tell the script to strip that work as an exception.

That way I will all 4 the files unified into one folder.
Thank you in advance

---

**Update:** This problem was originally posted back in 2013, now I have a solution. People help me assembled this script to fit my needs.

I added this as a *service* and assigned a keyboard shurtcut on MacOs.
This is the code:

```
on run {input, parameters} -- create folders from file names and move

    set output to {} -- this will be a list of the moved files

    repeat with anItem in the input -- step through each item in the input
        set {theContainer, theName, theExtension} to (getTheNames from anItem)
        try

            # check for a suffix and strip it off for the folder name
            if theName ends with " BAJA" then
                set destination to (makeNewFolder for (text 1 thru -6 of theName) at theContainer)
            else
                set destination to (makeNewFolder for theName at theContainer)
            end if

            tell application "Finder"
                move anItem to destination
                set the end of the output to the result as alias -- success
            end tell
        on error errorMessage -- duplicate name, permissions, etc
            log errorMessage
            # handle errors if desired - just skip for now
        end try
    end repeat

    return the output -- pass on the results to following actions
end run


to getTheNames from someItem -- get a container, name, and extension from a file item
    tell application "System Events" to tell disk item (someItem as text)
        set theContainer to the path of the container
        set {theName, theExtension} to {name, name extension}
    end tell
    if theExtension is not "" then
        set theName to text 1 thru -((count theExtension) + 2) of theName -- just the name part
        set theExtension to "." & theExtension
    end if
    return {theContainer, theName, theExtension}
end getTheNames


to makeNewFolder for theChild at theParent -- make a new child folder at the parent location if it doesn't already exist
    set theParent to theParent as text
    if theParent begins with "/" then set theParent to theParent as POSIX file as text
    try
        return (theParent & theChild) as alias
    on error errorMessage -- no folder
        log errorMessage
        tell application "Finder" to make new folder at theParent with properties {name:theChild}
        return the result as alias
    end try
end makeNewFolder
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You should either post [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) or hire one of the many talented developers in the [careers section](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It's a pity you get downvoted as I, personally, enjoy answering these sorts of questions, as it helps me practise and improve my own skills.

Thanks for posting your solution.  I think it's a great gesture and others will find it useful.

This script is a bit shorter than and uses "System Events" instead of "Finder", so will be quicker for large numbers of files:

```
    set IllustratorOutputFolder to "/Users/CK/Desktop/example"

    tell application "System Events" to ¬
        set ai_files to every file in folder IllustratorOutputFolder ¬
            whose name extension is "ai"

    set Output to {}

    repeat with ai_file in ai_files
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."

        get name of ai_file
        get text items of result

        set basename to reverse of rest of reverse of result as text

        tell application "System Events"
            get (every file in folder IllustratorOutputFolder ¬
                whose name begins with basename)

            move result to (make new folder ¬
                in folder IllustratorOutputFolder ¬
                with properties {name:basename})
        end tell

        set end of Output to result
    end repeat

    return Output -- list of lists of moved files
```

Just an alternative way of doing things.  Not that it's better or worse, but just a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could also save this as `script.sh` (in TextEdit in plain text mode) and run it with `bash script.sh` in Terminal:

```
cd ~/Target\ Folder/
for f in *.ai *.pdf *.jpg; do
    dir=${f%.*}
    dir=${dir% LOW}
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    mv "$f" "$dir"
done
```