# How to make Folder Action to watch a folder and if it sees 2+ files with same filename and diff ext, create new folder and move those files in folder

Tags: macos, automation, applescript, automator

I've been searching for weeks and have been unsucessful on finding a way on my Mac running Ventura to help solve this wish.

I have a lot of files that have the **same file name** and are saved with **different extensions** and all exist in the same folder. I am looking for a script to use as a folder action that will do the following.

1. Watch a folder and use it as a drop zone with a folder action powered by a script.
2. If the folder sees 2 or more files with the same file name, create a subfolder inside of the working folder, and subsequently;
3. Move files that have 2 or more with the same name but different extensions into the newly created subfolder.

Example;

Watched Folder Location is in my home folder named "Work".

```
Example Print.ai
Example Print.mkv
Example Print.jpg
Example Print.txt
Weird Logo 3454.psd
Weird Logo 3454.ai
Weird Logo 3454.png
Weird Logo 3454.gif
Green Bird.png
Green Bird.jpg
Lizard Jumping.mkv
```

Ideally, it would return the following results if run as a folder action on the folder "work" where all of these items reside;

```
/users/blaine/work/Example Print/
Example Print.ai
Example Print.mkv
Example Print.jpg
Example Print.txt

/users/blaine/work/Weird Logo 3454/
Weird Logo 3454.psd
Weird Logo 3454.ai
Weird Logo 3454.png
Weird Logo 3454.gif

/users/blaine/work/Green Bird/
Green Bird.png
Green Bird.jpg

/users/blaine/work/Lizard Jumping.mkv
```

Which should look like this when the folder "work" is opened.

```
/users/blaine/work/Example Print/
/users/blaine/work/Weird Logo 3454/
/users/blaine/work/Green Bird/
/users/blaine/work/Lizard Jumping.mkv
```

Any ideas? I have managed to create a shortcut that allows me to run a "quick action" and I can manually highlight files when sorted and create new folder from selection and automatically name the new folder the same as the file name without the extension, but there are thousands which makes me believe there must be a better way. Any help is appreciated.

These are the closest threads I was able to find on this topic, but they're a little too different for me to dissect and make work.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57465078/21894037

[Create new folder from files name and move files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14866051/21894037)

---

For Reference, this is the script I have currently turned into a quick-action or use as a folder action. It works great except for having to manually scan through usually around 10-20k files.

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set selectedFiles to selection as alias list
    set containingFolder to container of (item 1 of selectedFiles) --as alias
    repeat with i from 1 to count of selectedFiles
        set foldersRef to (a reference to folders of containingFolder)
        set foldersRefItems to name of (contents of foldersRef)
        set thisItem to item i of selectedFiles
        set fileName to (text items 1 thru -5) of (name of thisItem as text) as string
        if fileName is not in foldersRefItems then
            move thisItem to (make new folder at containingFolder ¬
                with properties {name:fileName})
        else
            move thisItem to folder fileName of containingFolder
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: I don't understand why you want this to be a folder action.

Comment: Sorry for not including that information—apologies. 

I’d like it to be a folder action because the files that are going in will always be named uniquely. 99% of everything going in that folder will just be 2 files with different extensions. Once I have two in the folder, it creating a folder itself saves me the time of scanning the folder visually since there are thousands of files that are consistently being stored. Essentially the folder is a large dumping zone for files I am sent from multiple people so having the process as a folder action seemed like the best option. I’m open tho!

Comment: Even if there was a way for this to be an action that could be run through Automator or AppleScript manually as an action at the end of the day or as often as I’d like, that would still work and save a couple hundred hours of cleanup and a way to make it better moving forward.

Comment: I see. FWIW, I would separate the drop folder from the storage folder (and sub-folders), but that's probably just my bias against using action folders for storage. Your second comment is probably how I would go about it but I can't really put myself in your shoes so maybe the folder action is the way to go.

Comment: Basically, your question is not a bad one if you have a lot of files with the same basename but different extensions, and you want to clean up the mess. Someone here put a downvote on it, most likely due to the fact that you are asking to write a ready-made script. This is not welcome here. Your attempt should also be visible.

Comment: @Mockman I think your idea is better about having the folder that's a dropzone be different than the destination storage folder as you brought up--great idea. There would NOT be a scenario where the dropzone folder gets two files, and then later a third one is added and expected to go into the already created folder.

Comment: @RobertKniazidis - Thank you for the explanation on the downvote and I apologize for asking for a ready-made script--I was more hoping that this was something that had already been created and I just wasn't able to find it. What I am currently using as a quick action that I converted into a folder action that allows me to manually scan the folder, grab the files, and either use 'right click + quick action' or a keyboard shortcut for the quick action. I'll add the code block above so you know what my current method looks like. I appreciate your patience and kindness a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Added to hot (watch) folder file(s) will be moved into the hot folder's appropriate subfolder(s).

```
on adding folder items to thisFolder after receiving these_items
    set thisFolderHFSPath to thisFolder as text -- this watch folder's HFS path
    tell application "Finder" to set allFiles to (files of folder (thisFolder as text)) as alias list
    -- get all basenames list
    set basenames to {}
    repeat with anItem in allFiles
        set end of basenames to my getBaseName(POSIX path of anItem)
    end repeat
    repeat with anItem in these_items
        set baseName to my getBaseName(POSIX path of anItem) -- baseName of file
        tell application "Finder"
            try
                -- if the appropriate subfolder exists then sure the file should be moved in it
                set subFolder to folder (thisFolderHFSPath & baseName)
                try -- required try block here   
                    move file (anItem as text) to subFolder
                end try
            on error -- if no appropriate subfolder, then 
                set aCount to 0
                repeat with b in basenames
                    if baseName is (contents of b) then set aCount to aCount + 1
                end repeat
                if aCount > 1 then -- the file should be moved if duplicate basename
                    set subFolder to make new folder at thisFolder with properties {name:baseName}
                    try -- required try block here   
                        move file (anItem as text) to subFolder
                    end try
                end if
            end try
        end tell
    end repeat
end adding folder items to

on getBaseName(posixPath)
    set {ATID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, "/"}
    if (posixPath ends with "/") then
        set baseName to text item -2 of posixPath
    else
        set baseName to text item -1 of posixPath
    end if
    if (baseName contains ".") then
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
        set baseName to text 1 thru text item -2 of baseName
    end if
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ATID
    return baseName
end getBaseName
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP wants to have a file moved unless there are least two with the same basename. I haven't tested this but won't it process each file added?

Comment: Yes, most likely so. You can fix it, but it will complicate and greatly slow down the script. You will have to check each time **whether the current basename is in the list of basenames of other files located in the hot folder**.

Comment: I updated the script to fix this.

Comment: I finally got to test this. It moves the added file reliably but the 'same basename' files weren't moved. Perhaps adding something like `move ((files whose name begins with baseName) of thisFolder) to subFolder` inside the 'required try block'.

Comment: I think some time delays are needed here to get stability. Because in my tests the script works, but is not stable.

Comment: @RobertKniazidis -- This is my first time not being able to solve this type of issue on my own, and it's my first time asking for help with AppleScript. Please forgive me for not replying back yesterday (the honest truth is that I took the day off to play the newest Zelda game that came out and I didn't realize that I wouldn't automatically get a notification when someone comments or replies on Stackoverflow).

Comment: @RobertKniazidis Thank you for editing the script. I am going to try it now on a smaller test folder -- I didn't mean to go silent. 

Comment: @Mockman -- You are correct, I desperately want to avoid making a folder if only one file exists with that name. 99.9% of the time it will always be two files only.

Comment: @RobertKniazidis -- Correction again on my end, looks like everything was filtered through as junk mail which is why I didn't see the replies. Just changed that now. 

Comment: @Mockman - After testing the AppleScript above as a FA from RobertKniazidis I also am not getting files with the same base name to create a subfolder or for the files to move into them.

Comment: @RobertKniazidis - When I move a few files into the test folder, I see the gear in the menu bar start to spin the same way it does as it executes any other Folder Action, but then it stops spinning and no movement has occurred. My test folder is located in my home folder, and I tried putting the test folder in a few other locations that don't interact with iCloud Files or other MacOS restrictions.

Comment: Setting the Folder action is a very capricious thing. **For me everything works**. Attention: in order for the Folder action not to use the **old script with same name** (old version), and not the newly assigned one, in the Folder action setup you must first **delete** the old Folder action (with the same names), and then **add everything again**. Also, first make sure that the new version of the script is not just copied from the site to the editor, but **saved** in the ~ Library/Scripts/Folder actions folder. Also, test first with 3 files (2 with the same name, 3 with another).

Comment: By the way, experienced users don't like to mess with answers about Folder actions, Mail rules, etc. because of this. You have to teach a beginner step by step how to properly set up these special functions, which is quite tedious.

Comment: Hi @RobertKniazidis - I believe it's worth mentioning that all of the things that you just commented that I have to do to make the folder action work has already been done.  I am not a beginner and have used Folder Actions for years, and this is the first time I've not been able to solve it on my own. I can see how it would be tedious to answer basic beginner steps, but this is not the case. I previously explained that I use folder actions and scripts, and included the current script I am using. I appreciate your help and had already done everything you suggested/explained with no result.

Comment: @RobertKniazidis - I am open to a different approach or idea, I'm only asking for help. I've worked in tech my whole life and worked for Apple specifically for 10 years training technicians. Automation has not been my specialty using AppleScript so I have been self-taught in Automator/AppleScript.

Comment: @RobertKniazidis - Update - Thank you for your help. For some reason, it took a restart of the Mac for the Folder Action to take effect, **but is now working perfectly** at the moment. I REALLY appreciate your help.

Comment: @RobertKniazidis _"experienced users don't like...because...to teach a beginner step by step...is quite tedious."_  What an incredibly arrogant and condescending attitude to have. **1)** I'm a lot more experienced than you and I'm perfectly happy demonstrating these things to newbie (although I note the OP is not a newbie). Others more experienced than I happily do the same. **2)** This is StackOverflow—our remit includes helping newbies learn the fundamentals properly.  These are, by their nature, tedious, but determine how skilled the newbie can become later. _Cont'd..._

Comment: _...Cont'd_ You didn't have someone to teach you the basics, but a lot of others (myself included) benefited from the patience of good teachers, so we pay it forward ∴ **3)** You don't have to answer a question. If you're not invested, you'll do a poorer job, so leave it for someone else. This here is not your best work, and risks passing along bad habits.  **4)** Teaching is learning, so we benefit too. The giving of knowledge to others begets understanding for ourselves.  It lets us consolidate what we know, comprehend what we don't, and cultivate expertise. 〼

Comment: @CJK Thank you a lot for the kind perspective. 

The script does work, it has saved me hundreds of hours--i’m truly appreciative.